# Syntax error at or near ")" when trying to get children from an adjacency tree

Tags: postgresql, tree

I was trying to follow the PostgreSQL [guide to get children from an adjacency tree](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Getting_list_of_all_children_from_adjacency_tree) on PostgreSQL 9.6. For connivence I'll reproduce the command it suggests here:

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree AS (
  SELECT id, ARRAY[]::INTEGER[] AS ancestors
  FROM test WHERE parent_id IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT test.id, tree.ancestors || test.parent_id
  FROM test, tree
  WHERE test.parent_id = tree.id
) SELECT * FROM tree WHERE 3 = ANY(tree.ancestors);
```

My understanding was that you simply have to replace `test` with the name of the table you're trying to access, and `parent_id` with the name of the field that contains the parent id. So I did that for all instances. However, I am getting a super vague 'Syntax error at or near ")"' when trying to run this command.

What could be the possible causes of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem with my SQL client, DBeaver. When I run this command in `psql`, it worked exactly as expected.